# Regular sequence in rings of invariants

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, invariant-theory

When I was reading a book in invariant theory, I've come across this assumption: "Let $f_1, f_2 \in \mathbb{F}[V]^G$ be a regular sequence in $\mathbb{F}[V]$". I know that we cannot assume anything unless we have at least an example. So, is there an obvious example of two elements in $\mathbb{F}[V]^G$ that form a regular sequence in $\mathbb{F}[V]$?

Thank you

Comment: Try polynomial rings.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Could you please explain more?